# UE4 Open Level node not working in cooked builds

Tags: unreal-engine4, levels, blueprint, unreal-blueprint, unreal-umg

I have a widget with a button that open a level and plays a sound when clicked.

The level opens well in PIE but not in cooked builds.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure the target level is marked for packaging, otherwise it can simply not be available in packaged builds.

Comment: The map is specified in the packaging Section of Project Settings. Is there any other place I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I guess enter projects settings > packages and search list of maps to include in a package and enter your maps